# How to use a backslash in between concatenated variabl 2 string values?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

In Windows Batch I have 2 variables `FOLDER_WITH_PATH` and `BACKUP_FILE`. I need to have a variable `FULL_BACKUP_FILE` whose value is concatenating `FOLDER_WITH_PATH` and `BAKUP_FILE`, with a backslash in between.

So, for example, if `FOLDER_WITH_PATH="E:\Backup\Proj1"` and `BACKUP_FILE="version_1.txt"`, then
`FULL_BACKUP_FILE` should be `"E:\Backup\Proj1\version_1.txt"`

How can I do that?

I have tried:

```bash
set FULL_BACKUP_FILE=%FOLDER_WITH_PATH%\%BACKUP_FILE%
```

and:

```bash
set "FULL_BACKUP_FILE=%FOLDER_WITH_PATH%\%BACKUP_FILE%"
```

but the value of `FULL_BACKUP_FILE` is wrong as

```
> "E:\Backup\Proj1"\\"version_1.txt"
```

How can I get the right value?

Comment: Please read my answer on [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564) It explains in full details the difference between `set variable="value"` and `set "variable=value"` and why the latter is highly recommended, especially on string values are later concatenated together. There must be enabled the __command extensions__ which are enabled by Windows default, but better would be the command line `setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion` below the first line `@echo off` to make it sure.

Comment: So, use `set "FOLDER_WITH_PATH=E:\Backup\Proj1"` and `set "BACKUP_FILE=version_1.txt"` and `set "FULL_BACKUP_FILE=%FOLDER_WITH_PATH%\%BACKUP_FILE%"` and reference the resulting value with `"%FULL_BACKUP_FILE%"`. That highly recommended syntax can be seen on thousands of answers on Stack Overflow with the tag [batch-file](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/batch-file/info).

Comment: If the name and value pairs are being read from a file, meaning you cannot change them, try removing the doublequotes during the definition of the final variable: ```Set "FULL_BACKUP_FILE=%FOLDER_WITH_PATH:"=%\%BACKUP_FILE:"=%"``` Then reference it using `"%FULL_BACKUP_FILE%"` if you need to quote it in use.

Answer (score 0):

You should define variables as `set "<<name>>=<<value>>"` and when y need to pass/call it, do so as `"%<<name>>%"` . In Cmd, value encapsulation is very weak .

If you rather want to edit the provided input, see this: https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html .

- But be aware that each time you reassign the variable, special characters in it will be unfolded . So you should avoid this .